Fastlane supply track_promote_to fails with Track "internal" does not have any releases
I am trying to promote an android app build in internal testing to production using Fastlane. When I try to promote the build with version lesser than latest release in internal testing, it fails with error Track 'internal' does not have any releases. However, if I try to promote the latest release, it works fine.

Here is the Appfile and Fastfile.
# Appfile
json_key_file "path/to/json/key/file"
package_name "PACKAGE_NAME"

-------------------------------------------------------
# Fastfile

default_platform(:android)

lane :promote_release do
  sh("fastlane supply init --track internal")
  supply(
    track: "internal",
    track_promote_to: "production",
    version_name: "1.05.00",
    version_code: "138"
  )
end

I have the latest release with version name 1.05.00 and version code 140 in internal testing(Google Play Store).
Is it that fastlane only allows to promote the latest release?

If you found an answer useful, you can accept it by clicking the tick mark(✔)  at the left side of an answer.

Key Points:

Rollout Percentage: By using this function, you can roll out the new app version to a small portion of users initially and then release it for everyone upon positive feedback.

https://docs.fastlane.tools/getting-started/android/release-deployment/
http://docs.fastlane.tools/actions/upload_to_play_store/#parameters
Setting Rollout Percentage:

After uploading the app with a given "rollout" channel, the percentage rollout can be set.
Value of 0% means the Update is not available to any users yet.
Each fraction of a percent of 1% is available just for users' initial testing.
The figure of 100% refers to its availability for all users (the successful uptake).

Refer these links :

https://github.com/fastlane/fastlane/issues/18386#issuecomment-801857449

https://github.com/fastlane/fastlane/issues/15639#issuecomment-553559557 proves the idea of rollout percentage with its range (0 to 1). )


lane :playstore do
  # ...
  upload_to_play_store(
    track: 'rollout',
    rollout: '0.5'
  )
end

Ranges from 0 to 1.

Official Fastlane documentation - https://docs.fastlane.tools/actions/supply/

New production version code should be higher than that of old version code.
